# Bootstrap navigationbar right align

Tags: bootstrap-4, navigation

I'm learning bootstrap and I'm trying to make a navigation bar with a logo on the left side and nav-links on the right side and I don't understand why `ml-auto` is not working in my code.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SmoothieBar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error? It seems to be working.

Comment: popper.js needs to be added along with jquery.

Comment: Can you confirm which version you're using?